# Which is the correct design pattern for my PHP application?

Tags: php, regex, oop, design-patterns

I've been struggling to find good way to implement my system which essentially matches the season and episode number of a show from a string, you can see the current working code here: https://github.com/huddy/tvfilename

I'm currently rewriting this library and want a nicer way to implement how the the match happens, currently essentially the way it works is:

There's a folder with classes in it (called handlers), every handler is a class that implements an interface to ensure a method called match(); exists, this match method uses the regex stored in a property of that handler class (of which there are many) to try and match a season and episode.

The class loads all of these handlers by instantiating each one into a array stored in a property, when I want to try and match some strings the method iterates over these objects calling match(); and the first one that returns true is then returned in a result set with the season and episode it matched.

I don't really like this way of doing it, it's kind of hacky to me, and I'm hoping a design pattern can help, my ultimate goal is to do this using best practices and I wondered which one I should use?

The other problems that exist are:

- More than one handler could match a string, so they have to be in an order to prevent the more greedy ones matching first, not sure if this is solvable as some of the regex patterns have to be greedy, but possibly  a score system, something that shows a percentage of how likely the match is correct, i'd have no idea how to actually implement this though.
- I'm not if instantiating all those handlers is a good way of doing it, speed is important, but using best practices and sticking to design patterns to create good, extensible and maintainable code is my ultimate priority. It's worth noting the handler classes sometimes do other things than just regex matching, they sometimes prep the string to be matched by removing common words etc.

Cheers for any help
Billy

Comment: You might checkout [Horde Routes](http://dev.horde.org/routes/).

Comment: You're over-thinking this. Your greediness issue can easily be solved by ordering the array from least greedy to most greedy, and your regexes can all be in one class. I don't see a more straight-forward or more clean approach than that.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a class for each regexp is very inefficient, you are confusing classes with data here. You could store all regular expressions in a configuration array or a separate class or XML file - does not matter. Then a single method could accept all regular expressions, iterate through them and perform matching. 
In case a season is not always match[1], you can use named subpatterns - that would solve that problem.

As for your order of patterns problem, you could simply put all patterns in your preferred order - from most specific ones to more general ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt this [pattern to implement complex case analysis](http://blogs.southworks.net/dgeffner/2011/09/26/implementing-complex-case-analysis/) to PHP. It's more or less what you've been doing. You define all the cases, you implement a condition which says when the case applies, and how to solve the problem when you are inside that case. The pattern will allow you to decide what to do if multiple cases apply (choose one, give one preference over another, or whatever you want).

I'd also be a good idea if you named your formats somthing nicer like for S01E01

```
SddEdd
SnnEnn
SDigitDigitEDigitDigit
STwoDigitsETWoDigits
```

instead of format1, format2.
You could also modify the pattern a little to use object instances for both the condition and the resolution of the case, so you'll be able to handle al the RegExps cases with a single class
new RegexpCase("S(?:\d{2})E(?:\d{2})");
and all the other cases that aren't just regexps with a class to solve that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a preference order for your order of patterns based on the parameter you want.
I think second answer really answers your question well.Also you seem to be doing a good job with your code.It seems quite well -written

Answer (score 0):

I personally would prefer to use separate classes in this instance, your code base will be far more flexible should you take that approach (ie if you really need to manipulate the string). If you take a look at how Zend implements Zend_Validate and Zend_Filter they have a very similar approach to the current implementation (loop over a property running ->validate() and ->filter() on the classes).

I would have a structure similar to this:

- App_Tv_Match
- App_Tv_Match_Abstract
- App_Tv_Match_Collection
- App_Tv_Match_SXXEXX
- App_Tv_Match_SeasonXEpisodeX

(Your naming may become irritating for the classes however).

However in the abstract I would have a setup similar to this:

```
Abstract Class App_Tv_Match_Abstract
{
     protected $_returnOnMatch = false;
     protected $_priority      = 1;
}
```

And my App_Tv_Match_Collection class would have the match classes injected - the collection class would then handle the sorting and matching using the match classes. If a Match class had "returnOnMatch" flagged as true then if matched I would stop trying and return this one (ie for the non-greedy ones), however if no returnOnMatch classes matched then I would return the one with the highest priority (either using sorting, or a simple loop in the collection class).